# Thread function sum_array() is unable to be called by main function

Tags: c, pthreads

I am compiling this code in gcc. This is not showing any output.
The function **sum_array()** is unable to be called by main function.
I have already included these header files:

**pthread.h**,**stdio.h**,**stdlib.h**

```
int s[4]={9},i=0,end=3;

int a[16]={1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4};

void *sum_array(void *arg){

    s[i/4]=a[i]+a[i+1]+a[i+2]+a[i+3];   
    printf("%d",s[i/4]);    
    i=end+1;
    end+=4;
}

int main(){

    pthread_t t[4];

    int i=0;

    pthread_create(&t[0],NULL,sum_array,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t[1],NULL,sum_array,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t[2],NULL,sum_array,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t[3],NULL,sum_array,NULL);

    pthread_join(t[1],NULL);
    pthread_join(t[2],NULL);
    pthread_join(t[3],NULL);
    pthread_join(t[4],NULL);

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("s[%d]= %d \n",i,s[i]);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**no output.**

Comment: This `pthread_join(t[4],NULL);` accesses array `t` out-of-bounds. Very bad.

Comment: Concurrent read/write access to the global variables `s`, `i` and `end` is not protected. Typically a mutex is used to do so.

Comment: Does the program end?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, from inside thread function you have to call  `pthread_exit` or add `return NULL` as the last statement.

Comment: What does "unable to be called" mean? And instead of just saying what header files you're including, provide a full [mcve].

Comment: put "\n" at the end of your  print , or use fflush to flush the data on screen. and correct t[1] -> t[4]  to t[0]->t[3] in pthread_join

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here

1) Always put "\n" at the end of print or use fflush to print data immediately  on screen

2) you are passing t[4] to pthread_join which is not defined and was never created and out of bound of the array you are using to it , so it waits until that t[4] exits which was never created